# Qt (4.8.2) GUI - Own main loop instead of QApplication::exec()

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to ask, if it is possible to use a custom main loop instead of running a.exec():

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window r;
    r.showFullScreen();
    return a.exec(); 
}
```

something like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window r;
    r.showFullScreen();

    while(a.processOneEvent()) {
        read_event_from_legacy_system
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

In GTK I could use *gtk_main_iteration_do()* so I thought there is maybe something similar in Qt?

Or is there any other correct way to read custom events from a specific legacy system?

EDIT: The events which a read from the FIFOs are not system events (such as X11) they are just a struct which is sent via a FIFO to realize ipc.

Comment: What kind of custom events do you want to read? On which operating system? Are they from some file descriptor? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: I read custom events from FIFOs in an unix environment.

Comment: I had a similar issue - I enden up running the QApplication in a different thread.

Comment: @MeJ: you should *edit your question*, not comment it, to improve it!

Comment: This might be an XY problem: why? Do you need to intercept X11 events or what?

Comment: Nope the events which a read from the FIFOs are not system events (such as X11) they are just a struct which is sent via a FIFO to realize ipc.

Comment: You could derive from `QApplication` and reimplement `macEventFilter()`, `qwsEventFilter()`, `x11EventFilter()` or/and `winEventFilter()`. Edit: I didn't read you last comment. Nevemind.

Comment: General, I'm looking for something similar like gtk_main_iteration_do(), which only does one iteration, between the iteration I could check if a event is stored in the FIFO.

Comment: I don't think you can mix the `GTK` and `Qt` event loops. If you manage to `Q_EMIT` a signal from a `GTK` slot please let me know...

Comment: I do not want to mix GTK and Qt, I'm just looking for something similar in Qt as GTK provides.

Comment: I have related question. QSocketNotifier (probably) do not send signal once FD HUP event was emitted, so writing own loop and listen for Qt Events is good solution, but events must be handled in another thread.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to react on a FIFO -or pipe- file descriptor (on Linux) using Qt

With Qt5 you would probably use [QAbstractSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html) or [QIoDevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html) and its [readyRead](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#signals) signal

With Qt4 you should use [QSocketNotifier](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsocketnotifier.html) and its [activated](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsocketnotifier.html#activated) signal (so call your `read_event_from_legacy_system` from a Qt slot connected to that signal). It can poll any file descriptor, including a [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)

There is no need to change the application's event loop (even if in theory you might subclass [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html) but I don't recommend doing that). Once you set up correctly your thing, Qt event loop will `poll` the additional file descriptor, and your code should `read` it.

Comment: The function *read_event_from_legacy_system()* does already react on a FIFO. I want to use this function and depending on the event I will pass it to my GUI. I also thought to create an own thread which just calls *read_event_from_legacy_system* and pass it via signals, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way.

Comment: You can and should call your `read_event_from_legacy_system` from your `QSocketNotifier`'s `activated` signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

Although this might not be the best solution for your problem, you can write your own main loop like this:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QMainWindow wnd;

wnd.show();

while(wnd.isVisible())
{
    app.processEvents();

    // perform your own actions here
}
```

Instead of wnd.isVisible() you can of course use your own breaking condition.

Comment: Does this solution have any disadvantages?

Comment: I used such an approach once in a while and could not come up with any disadvantages. It is somehow working alongside Qt but if you don't mind that fact it should be perfectly viable.

Comment: If I do it that way, I'm not able to press a button anymore :(

Comment: Won't work if there is  a splash screen at startup, etc.

Comment: Oh I think that is still possible. Even the Qt description for the QSplashScreen class makes use of QCoreApplication::processEvents()

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with following solution:

**PipeReader.hpp**

```
#ifndef PIPEREADER_HPP
#define PIPEREADER_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QSocketNotifier>

class PipeReader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PipeReader(int fd, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~PipeReader();
private:
    QSocketNotifier *notifier;
    int m_fd;
signals:
    void dataReceived();
private slots:
    void readFromFd();
};

#endif  /* PIPEREADER_HPP */
```

**PipeReader.cpp**

```
#include <PipeReader.hpp>
#include <QObject>

PipeReader::PipeReader(int fd, QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent), notifier(NULL), m_fd(fd)
{
    notifier = new QSocketNotifier(m_fd, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
    QObject::connect(notifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(readFromFd()));
}

PipeReader::~PipeReader()
{

}

void PipeReader::readFromFd()
{
    qDebug("readFromFd");
    int ret_val = read(m_fd, &event, sizeof(Event), 10);

    emit dataReceived();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyWindow w;

    if ((fd = open(SPECIAL_FD, O_RDONLY | O_SYNC)) < 0) {
        exit(0);
    }

    PipeReader reader(fd);

    w.showFullScreen();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I get all events read from a specific file descriptor. If you want to use the events in MyWindow just connect the signal dataReceived() with a public slot of MyWindow.